# CMake Compilation Error with Protobuf Library: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::GetTypeName() const'

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors, protocol-buffers, undefined-reference, open3d

I am attempting to compile a project using CMake that utilizes both the Protobuf and Open3D libraries. However, during the compilation process, I am encountering the following error:

```
➜  build git:(dev) ✗ ninja -v

[1/1] : && /usr/bin/g++ -std=c++17  CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/protoTest.cpp.o CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/polygon.pb.cc.o -o protoTest  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib  /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so  -lpthread  /usr/local/lib/libOpen3D.so && :
FAILED: protoTest
: && /usr/bin/g++ -std=c++17  CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/protoTest.cpp.o CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/polygon.pb.cc.o -o protoTest  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib  /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so  -lpthread  /usr/local/lib/libOpen3D.so && :
CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/polygon.pb.cc.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV2pg[_ZTV2pg]+0x20): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::GetTypeName() const'
CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/polygon.pb.cc.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV2pg[_ZTV2pg]+0x40): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::InitializationErrorString() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

This is CMakeList.txt for ninja failure:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")


SET(this_target protoTest)

find_package(Open3D REQUIRED)
include_directories("/usr/local/include/open3d")

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
link_directories(${Protobuf_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(protoTest
        src/protoTest.cpp
        src/polygon.pb.cc
        src/polygon.pb.h
        )

target_link_libraries(protoTest 
        ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES}
        ${Open3D_LIBRARIES}
        )
```

However, when I don't link my executable to `${Open3D_LIBRARIES}`, the error disappears and the project compiles successfully:

```
[1/3] /usr/bin/g++   -std=c++17 -std=gnu++1z -MD -MT CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/protoTest.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/protoTest.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/protoTest.cpp.o -c /home/ncistwlwgczx/Acquiring/src/protoTest.cpp
[2/3] /usr/bin/g++   -std=c++17 -std=gnu++1z -MD -MT CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/polygon.pb.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/polygon.pb.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/polygon.pb.cc.o -c /home/ncistwlwgczx/Acquiring/src/polygon.pb.cc
[3/3] : && /usr/bin/g++ -std=c++17  CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/protoTest.cpp.o CMakeFiles/protoTest.dir/src/polygon.pb.cc.o -o protoTest  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib  /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so  -lpthread && :
```

This is CMakeList.txt for ninja successfully:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")


SET(this_target protoTest)

# find_package(Open3D REQUIRED)
# include_directories("/usr/local/include/open3d")

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
link_directories(${Protobuf_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(protoTest
        src/protoTest.cpp
        src/polygon.pb.cc
        src/polygon.pb.h
        )

target_link_libraries(protoTest 
        ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES}
        # ${Open3D_LIBRARIES}
        )
```

I have tried changing the order of `${Protobuf_LIBRARIES}` and `${Open3D_LIBRARIES}`.
And I have tried reinstalling the Protobuf library and adding it to my CMakeLists.txt file. I was expecting the code to compile successfully and run without any errors.

Comment: weird that there's a freestanding `/usr/local/lib/libOpen3D.so` in your compile command- especially when it already has `-L/usr/bin/lib` and `-lprotobuf`. Can you show us what the compile command looks like after you remove `${Open3D_LIBRARIES}` from your `target_link_libraries` call?

Comment: OK, this is my mistake. I have edited my question. Is the information I provided sufficient? @user